# Does std::call_once work under VS2013 and below?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, c++11

I am trying to determine if `std::call_once` works as expected under Visual Studio 2013 and below when C++11 is in effect. An example is shown below.

```
// C++ source file

std::once_flag flag;
int main()
{
    std::call_once(flag, []() {
        // ...
    });
}
```

Microsoft's [Support For C++11/14/17 Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) does not appear to discuss `std::call_once`. I am not sure if it depends upon [Dynamic Initialization and Destruction with Concurrency](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2660.htm) or not. Though its a core language feature, Microsoft did not provide it until VS2015.

My question is, will `std::call_once` work under most versions of Windows (XP and above) and most versions of Visual Studio with C++11 support (VS 2010 and above)? If not, then what are the requirements to use it?

Comment: You can determine which versions of Visual Studio support it by checking the MSDN documentation: it is documented for visual Studio 2012 and later.  It isn't in the documentation for Visual Studio 2010, so that is unlikely to work.  However, Microsoft no longer support XP, so there's no guarantee there.  Your only option is to examine the CRT code, as per RbMm's answer.  (Of course that doesn't provide an absolute guarantee for versions of the CRT not yet released.)

Comment: I think if used *CRT* version not support `call_once` will be simply compile error. so if code compiled and linked - supported. how I can view now *CRT* not statically linked to any winapi  functions not existed in xp - instead it try at startup get it pointers - and if api exist - use it, if no - custom implementation. and about Visual Studio - we can use even 2005 but install standalone CRT/compilers (need overwrite `VC\bin` folder with new binaries) and use latest CRT, CL, link with old VS

Comment: @RbMm, why would you want to do that?  It seems like a completely unnecessary complication.

Comment: At any rate, when *I* say Visual Studio, I mean the compiler, not the IDE.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - compiler/linker can easy be replaced with visual studio - all what need download [Standalone compiler, libraries](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) and update `VC\bin` folder - with this we can use latest compilers/linker/crt but not update VS itself. so CL version != VS version. and about  `call_once` this already depended only from CRT version.

Comment: Technically, I suppose the compiler suite is indeed called Visual C++ rather than Visual Studio.  I *might* try to remember that in future to avoid this sort of pedantry.  @jww, most people are going to understand that you mean Visual C++ even if you say Visual Studio, so personally I don't think you need to worry about the distinction. :-)  ... also, I strongly recommend against using Visual C++ with a mismatched runtime, so that's another distinction I don't think it worth making.

Answer (score 2):

this depend not from Visual Studio (this is only UI shell) but from which CRT version you use and are this implemented in CRT. if your code compiled and linked - implemented. `call_once` declared in `<mutex>` and internally call
`int __CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Execute_once(
    once_flag& _Flag, _Lambda_fp_t _Lambda_fp, void *_Pv)` (from `VC\crt\src\stl\xonce.cpp` ) - this function call

```
BOOL WINAPI __crtInitOnceExecuteOnce(
  __inout      PINIT_ONCE InitOnce,
  __in         PINIT_ONCE_FN InitFn,
  __inout_opt  PVOID Parameter,
  __out        LPVOID* Context
);
```

which have equal signature as windows api [`InitOnceExecuteOnce`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683493(v=vs.85).aspx) (*available from Vista*)

`__crtInitOnceExecuteOnce` implementation (which will be embedded to your PE if you use static lib - `libcpmt` or in dll like `msvcp*.dll` if you use dynamic linkage CRT) - first look are kernel32.dll export [`InitOnceExecuteOnce`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683493(v=vs.85).aspx) and if yes - simply call this api and exit. if it not exported (XP case) `__crtInitOnceExecuteOnce` use yourself primitive implementation 
(if several threads in concurrent call this api with same `once_flag` - until "winner" thread will be do initialization (inside InitOnceCallback function (or lambda ) other threads will be wait in spin-lock loop with `Sleep(0)`
so this design for work in XP too and will be work

Comment: Thanks RbMn. Microsoft does not have a `__has_include(x)` or `__has_feature(x)` macro, so we need to use VS/MSVC version to chose when we should compile with it. We also need to know the limitations on platforms. From past experience, we know that the code will compile fine (even when tuned with `WINVER` to denote a minimum platform), but it will lead to a crash at runtime. We caught 3 or 4 bug reports because of the missing Dynamic Initialization and Destruction with Concurrency.

Comment: @jww if you have binary PE you can easy view to where you jump when call `std::call_once` - this of course can depend from CRT implementation, which you use when build PE. i look and view that `__crtInitOnceExecuteOnce` called. this function will be in your PE (if you use static linkage) or in DLL (in this case you need install vc package on target comp). and implementation on `__crtInitOnceExecuteOnce` undoubtedly designed for XP. if not - it simply be import `InitOnceExecuteOnce` and call it. but it prepare for not exist this api (xp only and before) and use yourself implementation if not